# Embed graphics/information to a streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

How can I embed information or graphics to a stream.
Like the "marquee" (IDK what's its name) in a football/soccer game or any other live event. (Score, time and logo)

[image]

I've to add a watermark with FFMPEG's filter like

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i info.png -filter_complex overlay -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://wowzaServerAdress
```

And I was thinking to change info.png with updated info. I had no idea if that could work, it was just a test. Anyhow, it gave this error:

> Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

So, basically that error killed my only idea. Do you know how can achieve this with FFMPEG or similar? I'd prefer not to use something like Xsplit.